# How can I get a column that contains the maximum value of a specific header in panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Suppose I have a table like this:

| Meat type | brand | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| beef | A | 10 |
| beef | B | 12 |
| chicken | A | 11 |
| chicken | B | 14 |
| pork | A | 9 |
| pork | B | 16 |

I want to get a column that has the greatest price from meat type chicken,like this:

| Meat type | brand | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chicken | B | 14 |

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) function. First, filter to select rows where the type is `chicken`, then find the index of max `'Price'`:

```
df.loc[df[df['Meat type'] == 'chicken']['Price'].idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a filter to select only the rows where the meat type is "chicken", and then use the "max" function to find the row with the highest price.

```
import pandas as pd    

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Meat type': ['beef', 'beef', 'chicken', 'chicken', 'pork', 'pork'],
    'brand': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
    'Price': [10, 12, 11, 14, 9, 16]
})   

chicken_df = df[df['Meat type'] == 'chicken']    

max_row = chicken_df.loc[chicken_df['Price'].idxmax()]

print(max_row)
```

Out:

```
Meat type    chicken
brand              B
Price             14
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter only chicken first. Then sort by price and take top 1.

```
df[df['Meat type'] == 'chicken'].sort_values(by='price', ascending=False).head(1)
```

Comment: I used your code, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```py
df[df['Meat'].eq('chicken')].sort_values('Price').iloc[-1]
```

**Explanation**

`eq` is like `==`

I am looking for the rows where `Meat` is `Chicken`, then sort `Price` values.

Default is ascending order.

So I get the last one with using of `iloc[-1]`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.